# Start/stop a background worker in JavaScript (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my JavaScript code I have some function that I call a 'worker' that checks if it is started and do some work

```
class Application
{
    async runWorker()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            while (!this.isStarted)
            {
                await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
            }

            //do some work
            this.DoWork();
        }
    }
}
```

I run the worker with the application starts by simply calling

```
this.runWorker();
```

and set `this.isStarted` to `true` or `false` to start or stop it.

This works fine, but there is some obvious disadvantage: it can take up to a second (1000ms) until `this.DoWork()` is called when `this.isStarted` is changed from `false` to `true`.

Is there a mechanism in JavaScript that allows to start and stop the worker immediately? Or probably a way to rewrite this code somehow?

For example, in C++ I would create a separate thread that sleeps when the worker is stopped and use what is called 'event synchronization primitive', but I have no idea on how to implement this scenario in JavaScript (node.js).

Comment: What is that worker supposed to do?

Comment: @JonasWilms `this.DoWork()` queries some external service with HTTP GET and monitors some parameters. When a parameter change it does a specific action.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a flag to indicate that the loop is supposed to continue. Then call the looping function directly:

```
  const app = {
    run: false,
    async doWork() {
       if(this.run) return; // Don't run twice
       this.run = true;
       while(this.run) {
          await Library.stuff();
       }
    },
    cancel() { this.run = false; },
 };

 app.doWork();
 // somewhen
 app.cancel();
```

Comment: Cannot figure out why the condition is `response is not successfull`? As far as I see your function will return if the response is successful. Right?

Comment: @alexey yes, it depends on your definition of success.

Comment: there is no 'definition of success'. Actually `this.DoWork()` calls a library that does multiple `fetch` calls internally and returns some data that I check in an infinite loop. And I am looking for a way to start/stop the loop.

Answer (score 1):

As I expect you're aware, JavaScript only has one thread.  You can't use threading techniques you might use in other languages for this sort of thing.

However, the obvious question is: can you just call DoWork() directly where you set the isStarted flag to true (I mean instead of setting the flag)?  That will start the method immediately, clearly.

You may not be able to.  DoWork is a longrunning process and you are interrupting the code where you make the call, and it will only continue once the method returns.  One way around this is to use setTimeout(DoWork, 0).  This puts the call onto the message loop, and it will execute once the currently-executing code has finished.  That isn't 'immediately' but it may be 'at a safe time to do it'.